# Como pegar lista de contatos por código no Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Como pegar a lista de contatos de um Windows Phone por um aplicativo e exibi-la em um `ListBox`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a classe [`ContactStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactstore.aspx) (que você obtem via o [`ContactManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactmanager.aspx)). Com a classe você pode usar o método [`FindContactsAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactstore.findcontactsasync.aspx) para obter os contatos, e com eles atribuir a propriedade desejada na propriedade `ItemsSource` da `ListBox`.

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactStore contactStore;
contactStore = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
this.lstContacts.ItemsSource = contacts.Select(c => c.FirstName);
```

Lembre-se que você precisa habilitar a *Capability* de "Contacts" no app manifest da aplicação.